# Load UIWebView's Contents into Email Message

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I have a UIWebView in my view controller. This UIWebView shows a PDF file. I have created a button. When the user clicks on this button, I want to send the content of the UIWebView via email. As a template I use the MailComposer from Apple. In this template Apple isn't using a UIWebView. Apple uses local stored data which works fine. So I am looking to send the content of the UIWebView, my displayed PDF, but I don't know how to do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using `-stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:` to get the HTML content of the page and using `-setMessageBody:isHTML:` to set the message body. You may want use a `<base />` tag, though, to set the page's base URL so relative URLs function.

### Edit

You could download the PDF and use `addAttachmentData:mimeType:fileName:` to attach the PDF to an email.

Comment: What would be the mimeType for pdf? application/pdf? And I got a warning at `picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;` Assigning to 'id<MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>' from incompatible type 'DetailViewController *const __strong' What could this be?

Comment: `application/pdf` is correct. The error you're receiving is due to your view controller class not conforming to the `MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate` delegate protocol.

Comment: How can I make my View Controller conform to this?

Comment: `@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController < MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>`

Answer (score 0):

What you will need to do is download the pdf and save it on the device and then attach it as per Apple' example.

[see one approach to downloading here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226615/iphone-download-pdf-and-store-locally)