# How to download PDF from a website in the app using iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, pdf

How can I download PDF from a website and store it on the iPhone App?

Please let me know.

Comment: What have you done to try and get this functionality?

Comment: I am a newbie and do not know where to start from. Can you please guide?

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226615/iphone-download-pdf-and-store-locally

Comment: Yes Derek you are right. I think that question does cover my solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I've done it is download it as a .html file, draw it into a webview, then print it into a pdf.