# Download file from web to iPhone (C#)

Tags: c#, iphone

I have a website wich allows users to upload / downloads files (pdf, jpg, txt, etc.).  It works nice as it is, but my problem is that users accesing the web on an iPhone (or iPad) can't dowload or access the file.  I've tried to use "Respone.Redirect" to the file, but it doesn't work.  I've use c# to make my website.

Do you have a piece of code i can use to make it work?

This is the code i'm using but doesn't work:

```
if (Request.UserAgent.ToLower().Contains("iphone") || Request.UserAgent.ToLower().Contains("ipad")) 
{
    Response.Redirect(Server.MapPath(fi.FullName.ToUpper())); 
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: iPhone don't download files, at least from Safari, which should be what you want...

Comment: The `Server.MapPath` returns a server-path, not an iPhone path.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the problem is with your code so much as with the phone.
[How to download PDF and store it locally on iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226615/iphone-download-pdf-and-store-locally)