# iOS: Download and save PDF file in Documents app

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, uiwebview

I want to download a PDF file then open it in a `webView`. I searched about that then I found this [issu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226615/how-to-download-pdf-and-store-it-locally-on-iphone). The accepted answer describes how to download and display the file. When I test it, I can not find the file in the Documents because it's stored inside my app. Also I don't think that the file is saved because the pdf is never shown in the webView even if I pass the filePath to be loaded. This is the code of the answer:

```
// Get the PDF Data from the url in a NSData Object
NSData *pdfData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[
    NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.example.com/info.pdf"]];

// Store the Data locally as PDF File
NSString *resourceDocPath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[
    [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByDeletingLastPathComponent]
        stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"
]];

NSString *filePath = [resourceDocPath 
    stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myPDF.pdf"];
[pdfData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];


// Now create Request for the file that was saved in your documents folder
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[webView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[webView setDelegate:self];
[webView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

And this is what I see in the log:

```
libMobileGestalt MobileGestaltSupport.m:153: pid 2828 (my_app) does not have sandbox access for frZQaeyWLUvLjeuEK43hmg and IS NOT appropriately entitled
2017-08-01 10:29:06.882562+0100 my_app[2828:1334057] libMobileGestalt MobileGestalt.c:550: no access to InverseDeviceID (see <rdar://problem/11744455>)
```

What is the problem with what I did? And how can I put the downloaded file in the `Documents` app of my `iPhone` in order to be checked whenever the user want like any other PDF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sandbox path Error

```
NSString *resourceDocPath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[
    [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByDeletingLastPathComponent]
        stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"
]];
```

Please use your sandbox path instead of bundle path.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
```

Comment: Can you please explain more? Where have I to use `NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);` ?

Comment: Try this.```NSString *resourceDocPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];```

Comment: Replace your ```NSString *resourceDocPath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[
    [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByDeletingLastPathComponent]
        stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"
]];```

Comment: You're right! It works thank you! Can you tell me please how can I save the PDF in the Documents or iBooks applications that is in the iPhone? So the user can read the PDF after the download any time without opening my application?

Comment: Thank you I used UIDocumentInteractionController and I let the user choose the app where he wants to put the PDF :)